# Why git automatically ignores a package named "security" in my project?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I create a package named "security" git automatically ignores it even though I don't have "security" in my .gitignore file(Both .gitignore files, global .gitignore and project specific .gitignore file). Do you know what can be causing this issue? Is it possible for "security" word is some kind of keyword for the git or something like that? As you can see in the picture below git automatically ignores it. PS: I'm using intelliJ idea on Windows 10 Pro OS. Also I created another package and named it as "scrt" and put the same class with the exactly the same codes in it, it seems to be ok, but security package still causes problem.

[You can see it in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uYDz.jpg)

Comment: `git status security`? `git check-ignore -v security`? `git check-ignore -v security/`? `git check-ignore -v security/*`?

Comment: It might be a feature in IntelliJ, not in Git. You can right-click it, choose the git menu and include it.

Comment: Besides `git check-ignore`, what's the output of `git ls-files -v security`?

Comment: Please check whether you have "security" has been added to "ignored Files and folders" under Preferences | Editor | File Types (open Ignored Files and folders tab) or in File  | Project Structure | Modules and see whether in "Exclude File" you see "security" .
Also it worth checking whether you have a file in .gitgnore.